# Signal R hub start hang up

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a .net console application that call a signal R hub method. 
I managed to configure the connection to restart after several failure and start a fresh hub instance after the retry count exceeded.

The problem is sometimes hub.start method will hang up without any exception and it did not enter the continuation.

Here is the code:

```
 private static void restart()
    {
        Logging("Restarting connection", EventLogEntryType.Warning);

        hubConnection.Start() // it stuck without any error after several retry
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
        {

            if (restartCount <= restartRetryCountMax)
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    restartCount++;
                    restart();
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckClientStatus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                restartCount = 0;
                Logging("Initialize new connection", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                start();//start a fresh hub instance 
            }
        });
    }
```

Is this a bugs ?
I'm using signalr version 2.2.0

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you show here.  You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just want to make it simple, basically this method is called when the connection is dropped. I don't want to create new  hub instance every time  the connection is timeout, so start the connection again without creating a new hub instance. if i put a break point it will hit the hub start method and then it will release it without any exception. This method randomly stuck.